# Referencing Spring Security configuration within Spring 3.1 Java Config

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I recently switched a majority of my Spring configuration to use the code based config in Spring 3.1.  However, now that I've switched, my Spring Security is not working correctly and throws the following error on Tomcat startup:

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named     'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined
```

I still have the Spring Security in an XML file, and know this can't be converted to Java config in Spring since it is a custom namespace, however, I am referencing it within my Java config file.  I also tried moving the applicationContext-security.xml configuration reference from the Java config to my web.xml without any luck.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Import(ServicesConfig.class)
@ImportResource({ "classpath:applicationContext-security.xml",
"classpath:dataSources.xml" })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.foobar")
public class WebConfig {
   // left out Beans for clarity
}
```

applicationContext-security.xml:

```xml
<b:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
xmlns:oauth2="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2.xsd">

<!-- Security configuration -->

<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

<http use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/error/accessDenied" 
        entry-point-ref="casEntryPoint">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <custom-filter position="CAS_FILTER" ref="casFilter" />
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="casAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<!-- Bean definitions -->
<b:bean id="casAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider"
    p:serviceProperties-ref="serviceProperties" p:key="1234"
    p:authenticationUserDetailsService-ref="userDetailsByNameServiceWrapper"
    p:ticketValidator-ref="cas20ServiceTicketValidator" />

<b:bean id="userDetailsByNameServiceWrapper"
    class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper"
    c:userDetailsService-ref="userDetailsService" />

<b:bean id="userDetailsService" class="foobar.MyUserDetailsService" />

<b:bean id="cas20ServiceTicketValidator" 
    class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator"
    c:casServerUrlPrefix="https://mycasserver/cas" />

<b:bean id="casFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter"
    p:authenticationManager-ref="authenticationManager" />

<b:bean id="casEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    p:loginUrl="https://mycasserver/cas/login" 
    p:serviceProperties-ref="serviceProperties" />

<b:bean id="serviceProperties" class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties"
    p:service="https://foobar.com/services/j_spring_cas_security_check"
    p:sendRenew="false" />

</b:beans>
```

`web.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<description>My App</description>

<!-- Context Params -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>
         org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>foobar.WebConfig</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Filters --> 
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Listeners -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Servlets -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
         </param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: I updated my answer with concrete example

Comment: I found this reference to be really good. It explains what each bean is behind the Security namespace http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do not use `security` namespace shortcuts and migrate all spring configuration from XML to Java. It will make fine tuning of your security much easier. I'm going to do it for our project soon after migrating to 3.1. 
You can find non-trivial almost plain-bean security XML config example [here](https://github.com/alx3apps/spring-embedded-tomcat/blob/master/etomcat6-test/src/main/app-dirs/x509dir/conf/etomcat-test-ctx.xml#L50).

**edit:**
Finished config (linked above) migration. All config was put into one method deliberately to make it shorter and to demonstrate, that you don't need separate spring bean for every filter. Of course it's better to move complex init parts to separate methods (marked `@Bean` if necessary). You can find working example in the `X509AnnotationTest.Config` on the link above.

```
@Bean
public FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain() throws Exception {
    // AuthenticationEntryPoint
    BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = new BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint();
    entryPoint.setRealmName("AppName Realm");
    // accessDecisionManager
    List<AccessDecisionVoter> voters = Arrays.<AccessDecisionVoter>asList(new RoleVoter(), new WebExpressionVoter());
    AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager = new AffirmativeBased(voters);
    // SecurityExpressionHandler
    SecurityExpressionHandler<FilterInvocation> securityExpressionHandler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
    // AuthenticationUserDetailsService
    UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> authenticationUserDetailsService = new UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken>(authUserDetailService);
    authenticationUserDetailsService.afterPropertiesSet();
    // PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider
    PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
    preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(authenticationUserDetailsService);
    preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider.afterPropertiesSet();
    // AuthenticationManager
    List<AuthenticationProvider> providers = Arrays.<AuthenticationProvider>asList(preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider);
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = new ProviderManager(providers);
    // HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository
    HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository httpSessionSecurityContextRepository = new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository();
    // SessionRegistry
    SessionRegistry sessionRegistry = new SessionRegistryImpl();
    // ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy
    ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy concurrentSessionControlStrategy = new ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy(sessionRegistry);

    // ConcurrentSessionFilter
    ConcurrentSessionFilter concurrentSessionFilter = new ConcurrentSessionFilter(sessionRegistry);
    concurrentSessionFilter.afterPropertiesSet();
    // SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
    SecurityContextPersistenceFilter securityContextPersistenceFilter = new SecurityContextPersistenceFilter(httpSessionSecurityContextRepository);
    // X509AuthenticationFilter
    X509AuthenticationFilter x509AuthenticationFilter = new X509AuthenticationFilter();
    x509AuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    x509AuthenticationFilter.afterPropertiesSet();
    // RequestCacheAwareFilter
    RequestCacheAwareFilter requestCacheAwareFilter = new RequestCacheAwareFilter();
    // SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
    SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter = new SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter();
    // SessionManagementFilter
    SessionManagementFilter sessionManagementFilter = new SessionManagementFilter(httpSessionSecurityContextRepository, concurrentSessionControlStrategy);
    // ExceptionTranslationFilter
    ExceptionTranslationFilter exceptionTranslationFilter = new ExceptionTranslationFilter(entryPoint);
    exceptionTranslationFilter.setAccessDeniedHandler(new AccessDeniedHandlerImpl());
    exceptionTranslationFilter.afterPropertiesSet();
    // FilterSecurityInterceptor
    FilterSecurityInterceptor filterSecurityInterceptor = new FilterSecurityInterceptor();
    filterSecurityInterceptor.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    filterSecurityInterceptor.setAccessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager);
    LinkedHashMap<RequestMatcher, Collection<ConfigAttribute>> map = new LinkedHashMap<RequestMatcher, Collection<ConfigAttribute>>();
    map.put(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**"), Arrays.<ConfigAttribute>asList(new SecurityConfig("isAuthenticated()")));
    ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource ms = new ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource(map, securityExpressionHandler);
    filterSecurityInterceptor.setSecurityMetadataSource(ms);
    filterSecurityInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet();
    // SecurityFilterChain
    SecurityFilterChain chain = new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**"),
            concurrentSessionFilter,
            securityContextPersistenceFilter,
            x509AuthenticationFilter,
            requestCacheAwareFilter,
            securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter,
            sessionManagementFilter,
            exceptionTranslationFilter,
            filterSecurityInterceptor);
    return new FilterChainProxy(chain);
}
```

Comment: If you don't use the `security.xml`, how do you set the `<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />` using java only?

Comment: So, as the original post notes, the custom Spring Security configuration needs to stay in XML (until the Spring team is able to change that). However, I don't think that reverting back to plain beans is the answer - this will negate all the advancements and simplifications that the custom namespace introduced and what you'd end up with is a much less readable security configuration. Instead, the XML config, which is simple and to the point, can be kept and the original error resolved.

Comment: Your taking some liberties on *"simple and to the point"*. Spring security is complicated know matter how you slice it. I use the XML and see the benefit but all that magic XML namespace (custom factories) doing stuff behind the scenes... its hard to figure out what is going on. Just ordering the filters is rather confusing.

Comment: The link to the security XML config examples was really helpful

Answer (score 7):

For those still looking for a way to use SpringSecurity XML configuration with a Java config web application. I got this working using Spring 3.2.0.RELEASE and SpringSecurity 3.2.0.M1. Here's the important parts of the solution

WebAppConfig.java

```
package com.foo.webapp;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.foo" })
@ImportResource(value = { "/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml" })
public class WebAppConfig {
    // other beans go here
}
```

spring-security.xml
*Note that I had to remove the default xmlns="..." from the <beans:beans> definition.*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/secured/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/main"
                authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.foo.webapp.WebAppConfig</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>foo</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>foo</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: I've tried this and got stuck due to dependencies between the java config and the XML file. What is allowed to depend on what here? Am I right thinking the XML config must be self-contained and the java config can use it?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for the above hints concerning a springSecurityFilterChain when Java configuration of Spring is used.  As I've worked along to apply these hints to fix a comparable error in my own code, I noted that the Spring documentation for org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer (the interface implemented by AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer) has the following relevant "Caveat":

**web.xml versioning**

WEB-INF/web.xml and WebApplicationInitializer use are not mutually exclusive; for example, web.xml can register one servlet, and a WebApplicationInitializer can register another. An initializer can even modify registrations performed in web.xml through methods such as ServletContext.getServletRegistration(String).

***However, if WEB-INF/web.xml is present in the application, its version attribute must be set to "3.0" or greater, otherwise ServletContainerInitializer bootstrapping will be ignored by the servlet container.***

I point this out because I noticed that your web.xml version noted above is still 2.5.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with Spring 3.2.3 and Servlet 3.0. The tick is to extend DelegatingFilterProxy class and named it SpringSecurityFilterChain.

```
public class ServiceInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] { ApplicationConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}

@Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
    return new Filter[] { new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter(), new SpringSecurityFilterChain() };
}

public class SpringSecurityFilterChain extends DelegatingFilterProxy {

}
```

}

Comment: I wonder why you are overriding all these methods. You'd have a more complete code example ? I'm struggling with configuring the security with JavaConfig only.