# Spring security concurrent session setup programmatically

Tags: spring-security

Is it possible to setup session concurrency programmatically? 
It is easy to do that using XML configuration like

```
<session-management>
    <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
</session-management>
```

but what I need is that base on some property in database I want to allow/prohibit concurrent session.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Spring 3.1 java configuration for spring security enabling you own concurrency control implementation instead of `ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy`. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013996/referencing-spring-security-configuration-within-spring-3-1-java-config/10017711#10017711) for java config example.