# Spring Java configuration with spring-security

Tags: spring, spring-security

For some reason (I really cant rembember why :) ) I decided to only use Java for configuration of a Spring application. Also I would try to avoid web.xml

I started with the follinging two java configuration files.
ApplicationBootstrap.java

```
public class ApplicationBootstrap implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    //public class Initializer 
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(ApplicationConfig.class);
        rootContext.refresh();

    // Manage the lifecycle of the root appcontext
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
    servletContext.setInitParameter("defaultHtmlEscape", "true");
    servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.active", "Production");


     // now the config for the Dispatcher servlet
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext mvcContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        mvcContext.register(ApplicationConfig.class);
        mvcContext.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("Production");
        mvcContext.getEnvironment().setDefaultProfiles("Production");

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(mvcContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/api/*");


}
```

and ApplicationConfig.java

```
@Configuration()
@Profile({"Production", "ControllerUnitTest"})
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan( basePackages = "com.consius.activework.server"  ) 
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class ApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


}
```

This worked as espected. No my problem started. My idea was to use spring-security and I looked for a way to configure spring-security using Java. 
After a while I gave up,, I found no way to configure spring-security using Java.
I decided to go back to XML for the security configuration.

I created a web.xml containing this:

```
   <filter>
        <filter-name>filterChainProxy</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>filterChainProxy</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

To the ApplicationConfig.java I added:

```
 @ImportResource( { "classpath:/spring-security.xml" } )
```

And created a new xml file named spring-security.xml

```
<security:http auto-config='true' create-session="never" realm="Restricted Service" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" access="permitAll()" />               
</security:http>
```

According documentation this is minimal configuration.

Trying to run this gives the following error (and I cant understand why)

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter filterChainProxy
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'filterChainProxy' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:549)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1096)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:278)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:194)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
```

Can anyone help me?
I guess I have done something obvious wrong,, but I cant see it.

//lg

Answer (score 11):

How about sticking with the Java config?

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    // ...
}

public class WebSecurityInitializer 
        extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

Conveniently, the WebSecurityInitializer will register the Spring Security Servlet filter for you! Here's a nice explanation with plenty of detail:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/helloworld.html

btw ... Without the above, it's also possible to do the registration manually:

```
public class DispatcherServletInitializer 
        extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) 
            throws ServletException {
        servletContext
            .addFilter("securityFilter", 
                       new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain"))
            .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");

        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }

    // Various other required methods...

}
```

This way, you can forget about that annoying web.xml. :)

Comment: I tried same what you suggested. I don't like web.xml too. But I still get `NoSuchbeanException. .` can you please take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32575242/nosuchbeandefinitionexception-during-spring-container-start-up

Answer (score 6):

The name of your filter for security should be `springSecurityFilterChain`, that is the name assigned to Spring bean by Spring-security namespace.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Further you have used `ApplicationConfig` for both root context(loaded through ContextLoaderListener) and also the web application context(loaded through DispatcherServlet), it would be better to keep a different context for both and load the Spring security one only through root context

**Update**
To clarify your question in comments - Spring MVC application has typically 2 application contexts loaded up, the one that you have specified using the `ContextLoaderListener`(call it the `Root Web Application Context`), and the second one loaded up using the `DispatcherServlet`(call it a `Servlet Web Application Context`), which is actually a child of the root context and has beans defined in the root context visible to it. The root context contains the core application related beans(services, repositories, entityManagers, security etc), and the servlet application context contains just the things required by Spring MVC(Controllers, view resolvers etc). Now in your case, you have specified `ApplicationConfig` as part of both the root context as well as the servlet context, that is not required. You can instead use `ApplicationConfig` just as a root context and use a different MVC specific context for the web application context.

Comment: I dont quite catch your second comment?

Comment: Added an update now, with details on what I meant in my second comment

Comment: @lg-lindstrom It is not required to include filter config this way. You can configure filter in ApplicationBootstrap. See greenhouse example at https://github.com/SpringSource/greenhouse/blob/213d2c742d472e602defcde801dd118e098d73c6/src/main/java/com/springsource/greenhouse/config/GreenhouseWebAppInitializer.java. You already have a separate context for dispatcher servlet but you don't need to use ApplicationConfig there.

Comment: I've tried to copy the configuration in  github.com/SpringSource/greenhouse/blob/….    It gives me the same error so I have started to thing that some dependency is missing. The "sprngSecurityFilterChain" must be defined somewhere,,, where?

Comment: It is coming from the Spring security custom namespace handler which registers the `org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy` bean type with a name of `springSecurityFilterChain`. You can look at this code - `org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser`

Comment: This is not fully correct. The name of the filter is irrelevant, in fact when having multiple spring security filters they must have different names. The important attribute is the targetBeanName of the filter, which by default is the same filter name. So if you change the filter name, you need to set the targetBeanName parameter to `springSecurityFilterChain`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring 3.1+, then you can try adding the context config pieces to web.xml; which will tie it all together. In order to simply get it working without web config, try something like the following:

```
servletContext.addFilter(
            "springSecurityFilterChain",
            new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain"))
        .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
```

Answer (score 0):

From [DeleagatingFilterProxy](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.html) doc

> Proxy for a standard Servlet 2.3 Filter, delegating to a Spring-managed bean that implements the Filter interface.

By default, this implementation will delegate all calls to a bean with the same name as the filter. (in your case it is `filterChainProxy`). So you need to define a bean named `filterChainProxy` and this bean must implement the [`Filter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html?is-external=true) interface

But Spring Security provides a bean named `springSecurityFilterChain` implementing `Filter` and suitable for spring security. So change the name of your filter to `springSecurityFilterChain`.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013996/referencing-spring-security-configuration-within-spring-3-1-java-config) may help you

Comment: I changed th name,, but the error is still there::
--
SEVERE: Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:549)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1096)

Comment: @lg.lindstrom just add a link to a similar question

Comment: Or leave the name as it's and point the `targetBeanName` parameter of the filter to `springSecurityFilterChain`.